# How to set up communication between two processes?

Tags: linux, sockets

I have the following situation:

1. A daemon that does a privileged operation on data that is kept in memory.
2. A multithreaded server currently running on about 30 cores handling user requests.

The server (1) would receive queries from (2), process them one by one, and return an answer. Each query to (1) would never block and only take a fraction of a microsecond on (1) to process, so we are guaranteed to get responses back fast unless (1) gets overrun by too much load.

Essentially, I would like to set up a situation where (1) listens to a UNIX domain socket and (2) writes requests and reads responses. However, I would like each thread of (2) to be able to read and write concurrently. My idea is to have one UNIX socket per thread for communication between (1) and (2) have (1) block on epoll_wait on these sockets processing requests one by one. Each thread on (2) would then read and write independently to its socket.

The problem that I see with this approach is that I can't easily dynamically grow the number of threads on (2). Is there a way to accomplish this in a way that is flexible with respect to runtime configuration? I guess one approach would be to have a large number of sockets and a thread on (2) would pick one socket by random, take a mutex on it, write a query and block waiting for a response, then release the mutex once it gets a response back from (1).

Anyone have better ideas?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain in more detail what the problem with your own proposed solution is? It seems perfectly reasonable to have each thread of (2) to write to its own socket as you suggest, and (1) `epoll_wait`ing on all of them

Comment: If you are talking datagrams (looks like you are!) a perfectly reasonable solution is to have multiple threads listening (and writing) on the **same** socket. This scheme doesn't require any external synchronization (for itself. You might need to synchronize external data, of course).

Comment: @SergeyA: I guess the problem with the same socket is when reading a response, trying to find out which thread the response belongs to?

Comment: @Smeeheey: If I have a 1-to-1 mapping between sockets and threads, then on increasing the number of threads on the server, I would somehow have to communicate this information over to the process (1), so it would start listening on that socket.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a viable possibility is to go with your own proposal and have each thread create its own socket for communicating with the daemon. You can use streaming (tcp) sockets which can easily solve your problem of adding more threads dynamically:

1. The daemon listens on a particular port, using `socket()`, `bind()` and `listen()`. The socket being listened to is initially the only thing in its `epoll_wait` set.
2. The client threads connect to this port with `connect()`
3. The daemon server accepts (with `accept()`) the incoming connection to create a new socket, which is added to its `epoll_wait` set with `epoll_ctl()`.

The above procedure can be used to arbitrarily add as many sockets as you need, all with a single `epoll_wait` loop on the daemon side.